# Como usar o zerofill do mysql nos migrations do laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel

Estou tentando adicionar o `zerofill` do `MySQL` nos migrations do `Laravel` mas não estou tendo sucesso. Podem me dizer como fazer isso ?

Segue meu código de exemplo editando uma tabela adicionando esse campo tinyint com zerofill:

```
Schema::table('tabela1', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->tinyInteger('campo1')->zerofill()->unsigned()->nullable();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não existe uma método destinado a isso nos *migrations* do **Laravel**, porem você pode usar a classe `**DB**`, por exemplo:

```
Schema::table('tabela1', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->tinyInteger('campo1')->zerofill()->unsigned()->nullable();
});
DB::statement('ALTER TABLE tabela1 CHANGE campo1 campo1 INT UNSIGNED ZEROFILL');
```

> **OBS:** Só lembre de adicionar o `use DB` no calls

[Referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35108133/define-property-zerofill-and-size-on-field-schema-migration-with-laravel)